# Compiling and running java program with other programs on build path

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I'm having trouble getting my program to run in the command line. projectA has projectB and projectC on the build path.

I run this command:

`javac -cp "projectB/src/":"projectC/src/" path/to/projectA/src/packagename/Program.java`

This compiles fine. All the .java files in projectA, projectB, and projectC compile into .class files. However, when I run the command:

`java -cp "projectB/src/":"projectC/src/" path/to/projectA/src/packagename/Program`

I get the following error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class path.to.projectA.src.packagename.Program`

I have tried running the java command with many different derivatives of the -cp, paths, and from different working directories. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your command, javac thinks that the package is `path/to/projectA/src/packagename/Program`

You need to specify the fully qualified name (`packagename.Program`) and add the path in your classpath:

```
java -cp "projectB/src/":"projectC/src/":"path/to/projectA/src" packagename.Program
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have proper class path of projectA

```
java -cp "projectB/src/":"projectC/src/":"path/to/projectA/src" packagename.Program
```

Comment: We provided the answer simultaneously, I'll +1 to share the love :)